# Methods A and B call method C. Now how to find out inside C who called it?

Tags: c#

I have some code in method C that will get executed based upon the who called it.

```
public void C()
{
    if(A called me) { .... }
    if(B called me) { .... }
}
```

One way is to use a flag variable. Set the variable before calling C and then inside C process the flag.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Code smell.

Why does C care about the caller ? If the code in a method is different based on who called it, maybe you need different methods

```
A() calls A_C()
B() calls B_C()
```

e.g. If class Baker supports Bake(cakeSpec), it should behave identically no matter if it is called by CustomerA or CustomerB. You may want to customize some aspects of the baking, via some configuration params in cakeSpec. However on the whole, Bake() should do what it says.

Need more info.. as to exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I know... but its an already developed and in production code I am working on. Maybe I need to rework my logic. Thanks.

Comment: @Aseem - Do the right thing... Fix it before the cute little tiger-cubs grow up and have developers for breakfast.

Comment: I am gonna hunt some of these tiger-cubs today for sure. :)

Comment: I've used the stacktrace in auditing. Instead of log("Bake", someInfo) and log("Garnish", someInfo) - just log(someInfo). In C++ or C# I would do this differently.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `StackTrace` class, but as Jon said, code-smell.

Comment: I think stack trace would give the complete call stack as a string. Anyways reworking my logic.. seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @Aseem Gautam: No, it contains a list of `StackFrame`'s, that in turn contains the calling `MethodBase`.

Answer (score 2):

The following code could be used to retrieve the las calling method:

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
MethodBase methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you *can* use Reflection to find this out if you *really* want to (I haven't done it), but it's a bad idea to use that in production code. Setting the flag, as you said, is a much better idea. In fact, the flag should have a semantic meaning, rather than "who called me". Finding out the caller method is most useful for logging and other diagnostic purposes.

**Edit:** Tried out the Reflection approach I was thinking of (calling `System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalGetCurrentMethod()`) and it doesn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

I would do this:

```
enum Funcs {A, B};

C(Func.A);
..
C(Func.B);


public void C(Funcs f) 
{ 
    if(f == Funcs.A) { .... } 
    if(f == Funcs.B) { .... } 
}
```

Comment: This is what Aseem is suggesting in his own answer - set a flag. While this approach has merit in the abstract (modify behaviour based on a parameter), yours is explicitly tying behaviour to the caller, which smells bad as Gishu points out. To extend the bakery analogy: you don't want a method that bakes a cake differently for customer B because customer B has a nut allergy; you want a flag to say "don't use nuts" which customer B and any other customer with a nut allergy can set when ordering a cake, but which someone looking at the Bake() method can instantly tell what the flag does and why.

Answer (score 0):

If this is C programming, I can achieve it by using function pointers technique provided that A and B have the same arguments. A and B will pass an identification information in one of the arguments for C to know who is calling... sort of WndProc() design in Win32 API where the message is the id and params are the data.

In C#, I think you can use delegates.

Answer (score 0):

you could send a parameter to indentify which calles c, like 0 for A and 1 for B 
but i guess this counts as bad programming ...